# Run a script when a package is updated?

Tags: debian

I'm using runit to manage my services and when a new version of nginx is installed, I'd like to restart nginx using `sv restart nginx`.

Is there a way that I can monitor a package or set of packages for upgrades and trigger a script when they're upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Debian, a possible way of doing this is by using apts built-in machinery. Apt can be configured to run a script on updates.

See for example, the package `apt-listchanges`, which "is a tool to show what has been changed in a new version of a Debian package, as compared to the version currently installed on the system", specifically, by showing new changelog entries. This package includes the script `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`, which apt runs on updates. The content of this script, in its entirety, is.

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs { "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10"; };
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::Version "2";
```

These scripts typically use apt's Perl or Python bindings. `/usr/bin/apt-listchanges` is a Python script and uses the Python bindings.

See for example the somewhat sketchy documentation on the Debian Wiki,
[AptConf](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConf).

Answer (score 1):

You can make [`dpkg`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg&apropos=0&sektion=1) run a command before or after package management operations. Pass the option `--pre-invoke=COMMAND` or `--post-invoke=COMMAND`; the command is executed with the environment variable `DPKG_HOOK_ACTION` set to the nature of the action. This isn't very conveninent because these hooks run once per `dpkg` invocation, not once per package, and they don't provide a way to tell what the `dpkg` process will do or did. An indirect way to find what happened is to log the state of the package(s) you're interested in before and after the action, and invoke your custom action if the state changed. You can also obtain this information by parsing the logs (`/var/log/dpkg.log`).

---

A more specific solution would be to hook into the standard mechanism that Debian provides for your problem. The `nginx` package (or rather `nginx-light` or `nginx-full`) calls `invoke-rc.d nginx start` as part as its post-install (`postinst`) script and `invoke-rc.d nginx stop` as part of its pre-remove (`prerm`) script. Replace the `invoke-rc.d` command by one that is tailored for runit and calls `sv`; you may want to use [`dpkg-divert`](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/118/Replacing_binaries_with_dpkg-divert) for that:

```
dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d.sysvinit /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d
ln -s invoke-rc.d.runit /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d
```

Alternatively, put your own copy of `invoke-rc.d` adapted to `sv` earlier than `/usr/sbin` on the PATH, e.g. in `/usr/local/sbin`.

The script `/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d.runit` or `/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d` should take care of implementing the [`invoke-rc.d` interface](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=invoke-rc.d&apropos=0&sektion=8):

- Support the syntax `invoke-rc.d SERVICE ACTION` where ACTION is one of `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `force-reload`, `reload`.
- Support the option `--quiet` (the only one I see used by package maintenance scripts on my system, I haven't made an exhaustive search of all Debian packages).
- Invoke `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` as described in the man page, if you need that (e.g. to avoid running services in a chroot or container).

If you only want to manage Nginx with runit, then make your `invoke-rc.d` run the standard one if the service name isn't `nginx`.

---

All things considered, if you just want to manage Nginx with Runit, then diverting (or even editing — it's a conffile) `/etc/init.d/nginx` seems to be the easiest way. Use the existing script as a starting point, and replace calls to `start-stop-daemon` by the appropriate `nv` invocations.

Comment: As I'm working in a Docker container, I get the following messages when installing packages `invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.`. Will this mean that even if I use an alternative (update-alternatives), that it won't run?

Comment: Also: `update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d with a link`

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Sorry, brain fart, I meant diversions (`dpkg-divert`), not alternatives. If you rely on `policy-rc.d`, you'd have to support it in your alternate `invoke-rc.d`. After thinking about this, I think that if Nginx is the only service you want to monitor with Runit, it would be a lot simpler to divert or edit `/etc/init.d/nginx` and not mess up with any generic infrastructure.